# How to query multipe values in 1 column using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the table fabrics such as:

```
id | fabric_texture
123 | 70:cotton,20:polyeste,10:cmere
```

---

How should I create a mysql select to search by percent cotton,polyeste..
I tried **FIND_IN_SET** but can't use the percent value.

**Update:**
Search fabrics have over 50% cotton or lower 20% polyeste..

Important: cotton, polyeste.. is dynamic

Comment: Do you want to search by the presence of `cotton` or `polyeste`, or do you need to specifically search for the percent values? It would help if you edited your post to provide more sample rows together with a sample query rowset you would like to return.

Comment: Can you provide example with percent value?

Comment: I want make the Search like: over 50% cotton or lower.. etc..

Comment: See normalisation- but not the kind that cookie propounds

Comment: This is horrible database structure. The reason it's horrible is because queries like this are extremely difficult. You should have a table with columns `id | fabric | percentage`.

Answer (score 3):

You should move `fabric_texture` out to a new table where everything is in its own column.

```
CREATE TABLE fabric_texture (
    item_id INT,
    fabric VARCHAR(32),
    percentage INT,
    UNIQUE KEY (item_id, fabric)
);
```

Then you can do a query:

```
SELECT t1.item_id
FROM fabric_texture AS t1
JOIN fabric_texture AS t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE t1.fabric = 'cotton' AND t1.percentage > 50
AND t2.fabric = 'polyester' AND t2.percentage < 20
```

To get other details about the item, you can join this to your main items table.

The advantage of this schema over columns in the original table for `cotton`, `polyester`, etc. is that it doesn't require you to hard-code the fabric names into the table structure. If a new fabric comes out, you can just add new rows with it for those products.

Comment: You might want the key to be `item_id` and `fabric` since it seems like you could have equal percentages of two different fabric types.

Comment: Oh, wait, you may have simply made a typo since your columns are `fabric` and `percentage` and there is no `fabric_percentage`.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, but you're right that I didn't need the percentage in the key.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend editing your table to have a column for each possible fabric type maybe then have and int associated with it for the percentage, then you can query

```
"select * from fabrics where cotton = 70"
```

or in your comment example

```
"select * from fabrics where cotton <= 50"
```

so your old table was

```
id | fabric_texture
```

your new table is

```
_id | cotton = INT | poly = INT | cmere = INT | etc = INT |
```

the int representing values 0-100 (0-100%)

from your example this would be

```
123 | 70 | 20 | 10 | 0 | 0 | .....
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is this colum store: 70:cotton,20:polyeste,10:cmere

Comment: well for each column say you have a cotton | polyester | cmere | spandex | linnen | etc columns each set to 0-100 then if you want to find a mix you do "select * from fabric_texture where cotton = 70 and poly = 20 and cmere=10"

Comment: fabric_texture is the colum not the table

Comment: i know but its example, i want add more type and dynamic it :D